# How to perform proportional meta analysis including studies with multiple scenarios

Tags: missing-data, meta-analysis, proportion

I am working on a meta-analysis of travel impact measures where I have the total measurements and the specific amount of increase or decrease. In each study, I have multiple scenarios for the measurement. How do I perform a meta-analysis in this situation? For reference I will provide a sample dataset here:

| Study | Travel time (Minutes) | Total Travel Time | Cost ($) | miles | Fleet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | 50 | 1.5 |  |  |
|  | 15 | 55 | 1.25 |  |  |
|  | 12 | 60 | 0.75 |  |  |
|  | 14 | 53 | 0.5 |  |  |
| b | 26 | 75 |  | 15 |  |
|  | 20 | 60 |  | 20 |  |
| C | 120 | 550 |  |  | 50 |
| d | 78 | 125 |  | 60 |  |

Thank you!